# How to properly validate decimal values?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am writing an input field sanitizer function that should check whether that input value is decimal or not.

Test cases:

- `1234`   - true
- `12.34`  - true
- `0.123`  - true
- `000045` - true
- `000.45` - false
- `.45685` - false
- `5..454` - false
- `55874.` - true
- `000000` - true
- `0.0.`   - false

I don't want to show a validation error, I just want to prevent users from typing a wrong decimal value.

This regular expression `/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+/` covers all the cases besides the 5th point.
I guess here the only method to use is `String.prototype.replace()` in order to cut the unwanted wrong characters.

P.S. This validation is quite similar to `HTML input type number` native validation, except the 5th point, which is accepted as a valid number type.

**UPDATED!**

```js
const rgx = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$/

const cases = [
  ["1234", true],
  ["12.34", true],
  ["0.123", true],
  ["000045", true],
  ["000.45", false],
  [".45685", false],
  ["5..454", false],
  ["55874.", true],
  ['000000', true],
  ['0.0.', false],
]

cases.forEach(([str, result]) => {
  const actual = rgx.test(str);
  if (actual !== result) {
    console.log(`Test case "${str}" failed, gave ${actual} but expected ${result}.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't want to prevent a user from entering from entering "55874." from your last use case because they may intend to follow that up with another digit, e.g. "55784.1", which is a valid decimal

Comment: Thanks for a note, Updated the question.

Comment: Try `const rgx = /^(?:0(?:(?:0*[1-9]\d*)?|(?=\.))|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.[0-9]*)?$/`

Comment: Case '00000' is failed but shouldn't.

Comment: You edited the question in view of @Dexygen's comment but you still show `"55874."` as a match. Floating point numbers are never written that way. In a comment below you state, "I need to replace nonvalid characters with an empty string.", but there is no mention in the question of replacing characters.

Comment: My point was, and I didn't communicate this sufficiently, that the entire approach seems flawed.  The only way I can think of doing this without an error message is to validate the field on blur, and if it doesn't pass, put focus back on the field.  And a regex isn't necessary, rather, simply `isNaN(Number(input_field_val))`.  Even then that can be quite annoying if the onblur gets fired because for instance the user is trying to close the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test if the string does not start with 2 or more zeroes

```
^(?!00+\.)[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgqV9G/1)

Note that your pattern `^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$` matches at least 2 digits as only the comma is optional.

```js
const rgx = /^(?!00+\.)[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/

const cases = ["1234",
  "12.34",
  "0.123",
  "000045",
  "000.45",
  ".45685",
  "5..454",
  "55874.",
  "000000",
  "0.0."
]

cases.forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${rgx.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: I need to replace nonvalid characters with an empty string.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Then how is this pattern `^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$` ok for all the examples except `000.45`

Comment: Please see updated version. `5645.` is also true as a user may intend to follow that up with another digit, e.g. "55784.1", which is a valid decimal as mentioned by @Dexygen in the comment .

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan This will also match a dot at the end https://regex101.com/r/AtjNgX/1

Comment: /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+/ this one matches all the cases except the '000.458'. I updated the question.

Comment: /^(?!00+\b)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\.?$/gm regexp doesn't handle "12.34" and "000045" cases correctly.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan But according to your question, `000.45` should not match. And it would also not match just 1 for example. See https://regex101.com/r/FZaLod/1 The pattern I posted takes all those matches into account. See https://regex101.com/r/MFilHx/1

Comment: /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+/.test('000.45') = TRUE , but I want that case to be FALSE.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan I have added some demo code.

Comment: That one worked as expected, the only problem is that it doesn't validate '00000' correctly. I updated the question and added that case too. Everything is OK except that one. Any kind of numeric combinations ( without decimal point ) should be TRUE

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Ok now it will also match 000000

Comment: The regex will match e.g. `0.0.` which can't be right.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning another test case. UPDATED the question and added it to test cases.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Updated

Comment: Worked as expected !

Comment: I know it wasn't part of the question but what about `'2.3e3'`? parseFloat would convert it to 2300.

Comment: Alternative: `/^(?:\d+|(?:[1-9]\d*|0)\.\d*)$/`.

Comment: @MikeM That is also a nice one, you could post it...and instead of hovering over the downvote button, I will hover over the upvote button and click it

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it quite justified being a separate answer, but I had done the work so I couldn't resist posting it. The "hovering" was tongue in cheek obviously.